# Как добавить свой элемент в контекстное меню по правой кнопке мыши в гугл хром расширение?

Tags: веб-программирование, google-chrome, frontend, расширения

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы была возможность добавления своего элемента расширения в меню, который вызывается по правой кнопке мыши?

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно использовать chrome.contextMenus API, указав в манифесте разрешение contextMenus.

(https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/)